# Is there a way to use SublimeText Jira Package user setting securely using login credentials

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jira

Is there a way to not store plain text pw for this package?
I have not found an integrated way to access KeyChain from Sublime (and I am not sure it should)

Example Settings from Package:

```
{
  "jira_server": "https://yourdomain.atlassian.net",
  "jira_login": "username",
  "jira_password": "password",
  "jira_default_project": "YOURPROJECT"
}
```

Comment: I suppose there could be some implmentation of the Python keychain_manager

Comment: You may get a better response by posting on the appropriate [github](https://github.com/mix86/SublimeJira/issues) page.

Comment: Posted [question](https://github.com/mix86/SublimeJira/issues/9) on github page